# Any Rails Plugin/Gem available to facilitate users to import their profile info from LinkedIn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any Rails Plugin/Gem available to facilitate users to import their profile info from LinkedIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope! You are on your own here.

To the best of my knowledge, LinkedIn do not have a [public API](http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=developers_apis). Its closed to a selected few partners. They however provide some [widgets](http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=developers_widgets), which you can utilize.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Then how do you think visualCV.com and comozap.com handling this? Do you think they are just scraping the profile page? If yes, is it acceptable?

Comment: As far as you willing to adapt to their changing HTML, you are welcome to scrapping.

Comment: Thanks, so screenscrapping it is. Do you happen to know of any rails plugins/gems that does scrapping in OOP way?

Comment: scrAPI seems promising but I haven't really tried it out in production. Works well on samples they provide.
hpricot is well known, well tested html parser. Pretty powerful and easy to use.

Comment: @Swanand - Thanks, on the surface looks promising.

Comment: FWIW, screen scraping violates the LinkedIn User Agreement: http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=user_agreement&trk=hb_ft_userag

Answer (score 1):

There now is [pengwynns' Linkedin gem](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin). The linkedin api does not allow you to fetch all data (some remains protected in their walled garden) but at least it gives easy access to all public data.